# How do I activate a sheet programmatically?

Tags: excel

Using Excel's COM object model, how do I activate a sheet? I'm looking for what to put in place of ??? in the C# code below.

```
// Note the currently active sheet.
object originalActiveSheet = activeWindow.ActiveSheet;

// Activate the target worksheet.
targetWorksheet.Activate();

// Do stuff that requires the target worksheet to be active.
// ...

// Re-activate the previously active sheet.
// ???
```

UPDATE:

After further research, this is the best I've been able to do:

```
// Re-activate the previously active sheet.
if (originalActiveSheet is Worksheet)
    ((Worksheet)originalActiveSheet).Activate();
else if (originalActiveSheet is Chart)
    ((Chart)originalActiveSheet).Activate();
else if (originalActiveSheet is DialogSheet)
    ((DialogSheet)originalActiveSheet).Activate();
else
    throw new Exception("Unable to re-activate the previously active sheet");
```

Seems like an incomplete solution. Does anyone have anything better?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in C# or VB?  Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x62t5306.aspx) page help any?

Comment: I'll take an answer in any language. The page you referenced shows how to select a worksheet. I need to activate a sheet which may or may not be a worksheet. Unless I'm missing something, the distinction between sheet and worksheet seems important here.